# TypeScript does not infer the type of CommonJS import (through require())

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

- My code runs in Node.js environment. I have installed `@types/node`. When I write `import http = require('http')` or `import * as http from 'http'`, the type of the object I'm importing is inferred:
  [image]
- However, when I write `const fs = require('fs');`, the type is `any`. Why is that? Can I do anything about it?

[image]

Comment: what typescript version are you using? Can't you just use `import` for fs as well? `import fs from 'fs'`

Comment: just use `import...from` and stop using `require`

Comment: @tobias the latest typescript version. if I create .tsconfig.json, `import fs from 'fs'` tells me that 'fs has no exported member fs'

Comment: try this `import * as fs from 'fs'`

Comment: Have you tried installing types for node? `npm install --save-dev @types/node`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I have

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

A possible fix for this is to import the types for Node.js.

---

**Full Solution**

The solution for this issue is to import the types for Node.js.

This is available as an [`npm` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node). It contains all of the types for Node.js.

To install it, you need to run the following command.

```
$ npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

The reason the `--save-dev` flag is on the install command is because it isn't supposed to be a dependency, but instead a dev (development) dependency. This will not install this package if, for example, your project is installed as an `npm` module.

After this, [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/#meet-intellisense) will automatically pick up the type definitions, and will add auto-correct your Node.js code, including doing some other handy things.

---

If the type definitions don't get picked up, then the best solution is to restart Visual Studio Code. If that doesn't work, make sure that this is in your `package.json` file.

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.31"
  }
}
```

*Note: The version was correct at the time of post.*

If it isn't, then add that code in your `package.json` file, save it, and run the following command.

```
$ npm install
```

This should install it successfully.

Comment: The problem described in the question arose in the environment where types for node are installed. I just did everything once again, installed them into entirely new project, even restarted vscode. Yet, `const fs = require('fs')` is still inferred as 'any'

Comment: Okay, that's weird. My solution works correctly for me.

Comment: how do you set up your app? I just did `npm init` and installed the types and tried to do something with `tsconfig.json` but without results.

Comment: Did you make sure your Node and `npm` versions are up-to-date?

Comment: node 16.5.0, npm 8.9.0

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure. But this is the recommended solution (I use it time to time).